# Irregular green patches on laptop screen when screen on, but black

Tags: laptop, display

I have an Acer Nitro 5, and I've noticed a problem with it. Some parts of the screen appear slightly green, but only if the screen is displaying dark pixels in that area. I've gotten it repaired under warranty, the screen was completely replaced, and when it got back, the problem still appears, just not as bad as it got before I sent it in. I'm very worried since the problem was still noticeable when I got it back, and if it gets slowly worse like last time, it's going to be a constant reminder that something is wrong. When I take the top two corners of the screen and slightly bend them forward or backward, the green spots shift. I think my screen is slightly bent, and that it's impossible to avoid this. What is the problem here, and is there a good way to fix it?